# Angular Subcriber for BehaviorSubject fires multiple times

Tags: angular

When calling the patchPreview method the subscriber fires multiple times. The latestAddress$ variable is a BehaviorSubject. I tried adding .pipe(...,take(1)), however this prevents the address from being updated. How can I reduce the number of subscriber calls?

```
protected patchPreview = (offer: Offer) => {
    
        this.geolocationService.latestAddress$
            .pipe(
                takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
                filter(value => value !== null)
            ).subscribe((address) => {
                console.log('called more than once');
                ...
                this.offerPreview = { /*sets address */ };
            });

        this.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. It should be "Subscriber"

Comment: Remember that a `BehaviorSubject` stores the last value emitted and make it available for the late subscriber. Depends on the situation consider using a `Subject` instead. Could you share the code that involves the assignment and declaration of the `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: You can also use distinctUntilChanged pipe.

Comment: @cybering thank you for your comment

Declaration:
`public latestAddress$: BehaviorSubject<Partial<Address>> = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<Address>>(null); `

Assignment
`...return new Observable<Partial<Address> | null>(observer => {
...
geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
...
this.latestAddress$.next(addressObj);

}); });`

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded to this question. I have found a solution to my problem in a different place/bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inspect observable `latestAddress$` for multiple emissions. But it's absolutely normal for observable to emit multiple times.

Also with each function `patchPreview` call you make another subscription without completing the previous and every `latestAddress$` emission will call subscriber as many times as function `patchPreview` has been run.

btw, changeDetector should `markForCheck` every time a value is emitted, not when the operator chain is set up and subscribed.

```
.subscribe((address) => {
            console.log('called more than once');
            ...
            this.offerPreview = { /*sets address */ };
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. Would I be able to copmplete the subscriber by adding .unsubscribe() at the end?

`.subscribe((address) => {}).unsubscribe();`

Comment: I would upvote your comment, but I lack he points to do so

Comment: If you subscribe and immediately unsubscribe you will not receive any emissions. But you can save the subscription and next time the function is called do `this.subscription.unsubscribe` and then subscribe again with new parameters. But there should be a cleaner way to work with your observables rather than subscribe and unsubscribe multiple times. rxjs library has many operators that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

The Observable emits multiple times so it's normal for your subscriber to be fired multiple times.

You could look into using [throttleTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/throttleTime) which allows you to throttle the Observable emission speed to the interval you set.

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote your comment, but I lack he points to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime) it will reduce the number of multiple emits.

```
protected patchPreview = (offer: Offer) => {
    
        this.geolocationService.latestAddress$
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000), // 1 second debounce time
                takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
                filter(value => value !== null)
            ).subscribe((address) => {
                console.log('called more than once');
                ...
                this.offerPreview = { /*sets address */ };
            });

        this.cdr.markForCheck();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I would upvote your comment, but I lack he points to do so